# Missing class for indicator field value [SUPP] of type [class java.lang.String] with JAXB and unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal a JSON to a Java Object with JAXB but I got this error :

```
    [Exception [EclipseLink-43] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [SUPP] of type [class java.lang.String].
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.travelsoft.cameleo.bookingprocess.data.ElementJson --> [])]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:191)
    at com.travelsoft.cameleo.bookingprocess.refactoring.action.process.SearchAvailabilityAndQuotationAction.execute(SearchAvailabilityAndQuotationAction.java:551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at com.travelsoft.cameleo.bookingprocess.refactoring.interceptor.ExternalInterceptor.intercept(ExternalInterceptor.java:62)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
```

The class' attributes look like this and the one which doesn't work is "originalType" :

```
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected StatusJson status;
    protected PriceJson priceValue;
    protected PriceJson priceRule;
    @XmlElement(name = "element")
    protected List<ElementJson> elements;
    protected PropertyJson property;
    @XmlElement(name = "travellerRef")
    protected List<TravellerRefJson> travellerReves;
    protected PriceJson nettCosts;
    protected InformationObjectJson informationObject;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected ElementSubTypeDefJson subType;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String originalType;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String groupRef;
```

Does anybody of you have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

EDIT : Here is the JSON I'm trying to unmarshal :

```
{
    "serviceJson": {
        "mandatoryService": {
            "element": [
                {
                    "descriptions": {
                        "description": [
                            {
                                "label": "CARBURANT J DEPART", 
                                "providerType": "to"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "element": [], 
                    "id": "TSE1", 
                    "priceRule": {
                        "priceDetail": [
                            {
                                "amount": -14.0, 
                                "descriptions": {
                                    "description": [
                                        {
                                            "label": "CARBURANT J DEPART", 
                                            "providerType": "to"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "originalType": "SUPP", 
                                "quantity": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "property": {
                        "processScope": "application", 
                        "quantity": 1
                    }, 
                    "provider": {
                        "sourceCode": "FRAM"
                    }, 
                    "transient": false, 
                    "travellerRef": [], 
                    "type": "SUPP"
                }
            ], 
            "priceValue": {
                "amount": 0.0, 
                "priceDetail": []
            }
        }, 
        "optionalService": {
            "element": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the json data?

Comment: Just edited the main post to add that :)